# Expression Trees as the basis for user defined query engine (using EAV)?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm supporting a multi-tenant system that allows users to define custom forms.  The data model is EAV based because issuing dynamic DDL to change table schema doesn't work when supporting multiple tenants in a single DB.  An upcoming requirement is to build a flexible query designer that allows users to setup simple predicates against the custom forms they've defined:

1. Custom Date Field  < DateTime.Today

   And
2. Custom Number Field1 > 1000 and < 1500

   Or
3. Custom Number Field2 Is Null

I had intended to build this query engine by dynamically spooling SQL strings, but I wonder if Expression Trees offer a more testable and type-safe approach.  Is this a good application for ETs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, utilizing expression trees would be a much better/easier way to approach dynamic user-defined queries. This simple class can greatly help building up dynamic queries:

[PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check out the [Dynamic LINQ Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) as another option.  It's popular and powerful.